# What is the TypeScript equivalent to `var x = require("somemod")();`

Tags: node.js, typescript, require, jsreport

In node.js I'm using `jsreport-core` and they do their import like `var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')();` with the trailing `()`. I'm curious what is the best way to replicate this import technique is in TypeScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm curious what the best way to replicate this import technique is in TypeScript

You need to split the `import` and the *function call*:

```
import jsreportCreator = require('jsreport-core');
const jsreport = jsreportCreator();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pulling in the `"@types/jsreport-core": "^1.5.1"` in `package.json`'s `devDependencies` and am using an [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), for example:

```js
import JsReport from 'jsreport-core';

const jsReport = JsReport({
    loadConfig: true
});
```